How to config NGINX to handle url latest/meta-data
I am using ZAP (automative scan tool) to scan my web security and I have an alert like this:
Cloud Metadata Potentially Exposed

The Cloud Metadata Attack attempts to abuse a misconfigured NGINX server in order to access the instance metadata maintained by cloud service providers such as AWS, GCP and Azure.
All of these providers provide metadata via an internal unroutable IP address '169.254.169.254' - this can be exposed by incorrectly configured NGINX servers and accessed by using this IP address in the Host header field.

the URL that tool scanned https://example.com/latest/meta-data
I copied a cURL like this:
curl -X GET "https://example.com/latest/meta-data/" \ 
  -H "Host: 169.254.169.254" \
  -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0" \    
  -H "Pragma: no-cache" \     
  -H "Cache-Control: no-cache"

It should return 404 not found, but currenly it redirect to: /latest/meta-data
Please everyone, support me write nginx config to handle this case. Thanks!
